# Interpreting mathematical notation of the perspective transform according to openCV?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, machine-learning, image-processing, homogeneous-equation

Below is two notations of the camera perspective transform acording to openCV:

Link:http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.1_org/py/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

[image]

**What i literally don't understand is how 1 and 2 are mathematically similar?**
**How to come to 2 from 1?**

Comment: If I remember correctly from my Robotic system design subject, the transformation from 1 to 2 is not easy to do, so expect a long answer if/when one arrives. (I don't have time to answer now unfortunately).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Thanks for the link. I understand that the first formula is written in Homogeneous coordinates and the second in Cartesian coordinates. However, do you mean that this is the difference between them? if yes, the bridge between them is nothing but normalizing or transformation between the two coordinate systems?

Comment: Indeed. Rewrite (1) to move the translation out of the matrix as an addition, then project to remove the 4th coordinate component.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Thats actually the bottleneck of my problem. I don't come to 2 from 1 when i do your steps. Perhaps you know know a link for this transformaiton. would be thankful:)